# Indexing nested data with Solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to index nested data with solr from an existing sql database. The DB has this structure 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/images/employees-schema.png

My db-schema.xml is the following:

```
<document>
    <entity name="employees"
            rootEntity="true"
            query="select emp_no as 'id', first_name, last_name from employees limit 10;">
        <field column="id" />
        <field column="first_name" />
        <field column="last_name" />
        <entity child="true"
                name="dept_emp"
                query="select emp_no, dept_no from dept_emp where dept_emp.emp_no=${employees.id}">
            <field column="dept_no" name='dept_no'/>
        </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
```

and my managed-schema.xml for the solr is this:

```
    <field name="first_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="last_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="dept_no" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=null] missing required field: dept_no
```

Even if I remove

```
<field name="dept_no" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

I get the error the last_name is missing. If I remove the nested entity everything works fine.
Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens cause the fact of requiring a field is applied ALSO to parent docs. So your parent docs need to have those fields too, even if they just make sense for the children.

The same issue will show up with the 'id' field...Just remove the required attribute.

Edit: to keep the required attr, add this (just for dept_no shown here, do the  same for the rest):

```
<entity name="employees"
        rootEntity="true"
        query="select emp_no as 'id', first_name, last_name, 'DUMMY' as dept_no from employees limit 10;">
    <field column="id" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works that way, but is there a way to add some of the fields as required, so that i can see if there is something wrong with the data ?

Comment: And is there a better approach to index relational data from an existing database ?

Comment: you can keep the 'required' attribute if you pass a value (a dummy value) in the children too for example.  Regarding a 'better' way...as always it depends, you can of course implement some code (using Sorlj if in java) to index the db, it is much more flexible, but it is also more work

Comment: And how do you pass a dummy field, just add a <field> with a column name the same as the parent's ?